# Python beautifulsoup new tags and organising input

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am having difficulty with creating new tags and arranging them in the right order using beautifulsoup for python. I wrote a function which will read questions, links, number them and automatically add them to a html document. It is meant to add short html segments to the file.

This is my function:

```
def new_content(counter, button, link):    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("content_template.htm") as insert:
    content = BeautifulSoup(insert, "html.parser")

    #Find the tag you wish to append to and the tag you want to append before.
    original_tag = content.find("body")

    #Create & append new tags.
    new_tag = content.new_tag("button")
    new_tag["class"] = "accordion"
    original_tag.append(new_tag)
    new_tag.string = button

    new_tag = content.new_tag("div")
    new_tag["class"] = "panel"
    original_tag.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = content.new_tag("p")
    original_tag.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = content.new_tag("a", href=link)
    original_tag.p.append(new_tag)
    original_tag.a.string = str(counter) + ". " + link

    #Close all open files!
    insert.close()

    #Now write everything to the file!
    with open("content.htm", 'w') as output:
        output.write(content.prettify())
        output.close()

new_content(1, "QUESTION", "ANSWER.htm")
new_content(2, "SECOND QUESTION", "SECOND ANSWER.htm")
new_content(3, "THIRD QUESTION", "THIRD ANSWER.htm")
```

This is how each html segment should be organized:

```
<button class="accordion"> QUESTION </button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><a href = "ANSWER.htm">ANSWER</a></p>
</div>
```

The above segment of code recurs within "content_template.htm" file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<button class="accordion"> QUESTION </button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><a href = "ANSWER.htm">ANSWER</a></p>
</div>

<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, my first line works perfectly. Then the subsequent lines get garbled and added to the document willy-nilly and the whole thing becomes a mess. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong with the function?

Comment: Problem statement isn't very clear; first line of what works perfectly (code or generated HTML output)? Would like to try and provide help, but don't yet understand where the problem is or what messy output your getting. Further clarification of input, current output, and desired output may help us provide possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression: `original_tag.p.append(new_tag)` will append the new tag to the first `<p>` tag it finds in the document.
When you call `new_content` for the second and third time, the first `<p>` tag is the tag you created in your first function call, not the new tag that you just created.
The same thing happens with `original_tag.a.string`, so use `new_tag.string` instead.

A possible solution is to create a new empty `BeautifulSoup` object and append your tags to it.
Then you can add them to your original `BeautifulSoup` object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def new_content(counter, button, link):  
    with open("content_template.htm") as insert:
        content = BeautifulSoup(insert, "html.parser")
    body = content.find("body")

    new_tag = content.new_tag("button")
    new_tag["class"] = "accordion"
    new_tag.string = button
    body.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = content.new_tag("div")
    new_tag["class"] = "panel"
    body.append(new_tag)

    new_soup = BeautifulSoup("", "html.parser")
    new_tag = new_soup.new_tag("p")
    new_soup.append(new_tag)

    new_tag = new_soup.new_tag("a", href=link)
    new_tag.string = str(counter) + ". " + link
    new_soup.p.append(new_tag)
    body.append(new_soup.p)

    with open("content.htm", 'w') as output:
        output.write(content.prettify())

new_content(1, "QUESTION", "ANSWER.htm")
new_content(2, "SECOND QUESTION", "SECOND ANSWER.htm")
new_content(3, "THIRD QUESTION", "THIRD ANSWER.htm")
```